# Error 403 - Download failed

Tags: http, powershell, download

I'm writing a PowerShell script, which should download a .csv file from a link.

I tried it like this:

```
$us = "user"
$pw = "password"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($us, $pw)
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$pfad)
```

but I get the following 403 error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I am able to download a .png from another page like that. And if I type the link in my browser I am able to download this .csv file too.

Edit 12.10.15:
I found a mistake. I had " " in the url. Now I replaced all " " with "%20".
but I still have this error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks OK to me, but your user doesn't seem to have access to the file. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) on error 403:

> **Difference from status "401 Unauthorized"**
>
> Status codes 401 (Unauthorized) and 403 (Forbidden) have distinct meanings.
>   [...]
>   A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:
>
> - Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
> - The operation is forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing return code 403 when directory listing has been disabled.

You probably need to check the server logs for more information about why the request was denied.

Comment: Badly I don't have any error-logs on the server :/ And I think I should have the right permissions. Because if I take the generated url and open it with the IE, I'm able to download the file.

Comment: Without information about why the server thinks you're not allowed to access the file there's not much else I could tell you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the remote server doesn't like you.
You may have to add some credentials to your code to confirm who you are.
Can you connect to the server usually without having to use any username or password details?

Comment: Yes, if I type the link in my IE I'm able to download the file without credentials.

Comment: i have the same problem. i can download a file using google browse to pasted the line.  but programmatically, i get 403.  Were you able to solve this?